# Freeradius and bash script for login

Tags: bash, radius, freeradius

I use Exec-Program-Wait in Freeradius 3. On the users file i have:

```
DEFAULT Auth-Type := Accept
    Exec-Program-Wait = "/etc/raddb/serp.sh '%{User-Name}' '%{User-Password}' '%{Client-IP-Address}'"
```

And in /etc/raddb/serp.sh i have:

```
#!/bin/bash

USERNAME="${1}"
PASSWORD="${2}"

PHP_RESULT=`php-cgi -f /serp/www/prod/scripts/login.php controller=radius username="${USERNAME}" password="${PASSWORD}"`

if [ "${PHP_RESULT}" == "1" ]; then
        echo "SERP: Bledny login lub haslo"
        exit 1
fi

if [ "${PHP_RESULT}" == "2" ]; then
        echo "SERP: Brak uprawnien do uzywania Radius"
        exit 1
fi

if [ "${PHP_RESULT}" == "0" ]; then
        echo "Reply-Message += \"Hello, ${USERNAME}\","
        echo "Reply-Message += \"PATH=$PATH\","
        echo Framed-IP-Address = 255.255.255.255
        exit 0
fi

echo "SERP: Blad wewnetrzny skryptu logowania"
exit 1
```

When testing script, it works great, but on debug in freeradius i get:

```
Received Access-Request Id 219 from 127.0.0.1:53387 to 127.0.0.1:1812 length 80
        User-Name = 'nowakowski'
        User-Password = '***'
        NAS-IP-Address = 192.168.0.10
        NAS-Port = 0
        Message-Authenticator = 0x0dfdc24db932d55c2f02cee61a038824
(2) Received Access-Request packet from host 127.0.0.1 port 53387, id=219, length=80
(2)     User-Name = 'nowakowski'
(2)     User-Password = '***'
(2)     NAS-IP-Address = 192.168.0.10
(2)     NAS-Port = 0
(2)     Message-Authenticator = 0x0dfdc24db932d55c2f02cee61a038824
(2) # Executing section authorize from file /etc/raddb/sites-enabled/default
(2)   authorize {
(2)   filter_username filter_username {
(2)     if (!&User-Name)
(2)     if (!&User-Name)  -> FALSE
(2)     if (&User-Name =~ / /)
(2)     if (&User-Name =~ / /)  -> FALSE
(2)     if (&User-Name =~ /@.*@/ )
(2)     if (&User-Name =~ /@.*@/ )  -> FALSE
(2)     if (&User-Name =~ /\\.\\./ )
(2)     if (&User-Name =~ /\\.\\./ )  -> FALSE
(2)     if ((&User-Name =~ /@/) && (&User-Name !~ /@(.+)\\.(.+)$/))
(2)     if ((&User-Name =~ /@/) && (&User-Name !~ /@(.+)\\.(.+)$/))   -> FALSE
(2)     if (&User-Name =~ /\\.$/)
(2)     if (&User-Name =~ /\\.$/)   -> FALSE
(2)     if (&User-Name =~ /@\\./)
(2)     if (&User-Name =~ /@\\./)   -> FALSE
(2)   } # filter_username filter_username = notfound
(2)   [preprocess] = ok
(2)   operator-name.authorize operator-name.authorize {
(2)     if ("%{client:Operator-Name}")
(2) Client does not contain config item "Operator-Name"
(2) EXPAND %{client:Operator-Name}
(2)    -->
(2)     if ("%{client:Operator-Name}")  -> FALSE
(2)   } # operator-name.authorize operator-name.authorize = ok
(2)   cui.authorize cui.authorize {
(2)     if ("%{client:add_cui}" == 'yes')
(2) Client does not contain config item "add_cui"
(2) EXPAND %{client:add_cui}
(2)    -->
(2)     if ("%{client:add_cui}" == 'yes')  -> FALSE
(2)   } # cui.authorize cui.authorize = ok
(2)  auth_log : EXPAND /var/log/radius/radacct/%{%{Packet-Src-IP-Address}:-%{Packet-Src-IPv6-Address}}/auth-detail-%Y%m%d
(2)  auth_log :    --> /var/log/radius/radacct/127.0.0.1/auth-detail-20170517
(2)  auth_log : /var/log/radius/radacct/%{%{Packet-Src-IP-Address}:-%{Packet-Src-IPv6-Address}}/auth-detail-%Y%m%d expands to /var/log/radius/radacct/127.0.0.1/auth-detail-20170517
(2)  auth_log : EXPAND %t
(2)  auth_log :    --> Wed May 17 17:25:23 2017
(2)   [auth_log] = ok
(2)   [chap] = noop
(2)   [mschap] = noop
(2)   [digest] = noop
(2)  suffix : Checking for suffix after "@"
(2)  suffix : No '@' in User-Name = "nowakowski", looking up realm NULL
(2)  suffix : No such realm "NULL"
(2)   [suffix] = noop
(2)  ntdomain : Checking for prefix before "\"
(2)  ntdomain : No '\' in User-Name = "nowakowski", looking up realm NULL
(2)  ntdomain : No such realm "NULL"
(2)   [ntdomain] = noop
(2)  eap : No EAP-Message, not doing EAP
(2)   [eap] = noop
(2)   [unix] = notfound
(2)  files : users: Matched entry DEFAULT at line 1
(2)  files : EXPAND /etc/raddb/serp.sh '%{User-Name}' '%{User-Password}' '%{Client-IP-Address}'
(2)  files :    --> /etc/raddb/serp.sh 'nowakowski' '***' '127.0.0.1'
(2)   [files] = ok
(2)   [expiration] = noop
(2)   [logintime] = noop
(2)  WARNING: pap : Auth-Type already set.  Not setting to PAP
(2)   [pap] = noop
(2)   update control {
Executing: /etc/raddb/serp.sh '%{User-Name}' '%{User-Password}' '%{Client-IP-Address}':
(2) EXPAND %{User-Name}
(2)    --> nowakowski
(2) EXPAND %{User-Password}
(2)    --> ***
(2) EXPAND %{Client-IP-Address}
(2)    --> 127.0.0.1
Program returned code (0) and output 'Reply-Message += "Hello, nowakowski", Reply-Message += "PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin", Framed-IP-Address = 255.255.255.255'
(2)   } # update control = invalid
(2)  } #  authorize = invalid
(2) Using Post-Auth-Type Reject
(2) # Executing group from file /etc/raddb/sites-enabled/default
(2)  Post-Auth-Type REJECT {
(2)  attr_filter.access_reject : EXPAND %{User-Name}
(2)  attr_filter.access_reject :    --> nowakowski
(2)  attr_filter.access_reject : Matched entry DEFAULT at line 11
(2)   [attr_filter.access_reject] = updated
(2)  eap : Request didn't contain an EAP-Message, not inserting EAP-Failure
(2)   [eap] = noop
(2)   remove_reply_message_if_eap remove_reply_message_if_eap {
(2)     if (&reply:EAP-Message && &reply:Reply-Message)
(2)     if (&reply:EAP-Message && &reply:Reply-Message)  -> FALSE
(2)    else else {
(2)     [noop] = noop
(2)    } # else else = noop
(2)   } # remove_reply_message_if_eap remove_reply_message_if_eap = noop
(2)  } # Post-Auth-Type REJECT = updated
(2) Delaying response for 1 seconds
Waking up in 0.2 seconds.
Waking up in 0.7 seconds.
(2) Sending delayed response
(2) Sending Access-Reject packet to host 127.0.0.1 port 53387, id=219, length=0
Sending Access-Reject Id 219 from 127.0.0.1:1812 to 127.0.0.1:53387
Waking up in 3.9 seconds.
(2) Cleaning up request packet ID 219 with timestamp +366
Ready to process requests
```

With which i can not log in. What should i send in rensponse on bash script to make login possible?

Comment: Looks like the users file entry works, but your call in the control section didn't.  Can you include the contents of that ``update control {}`` section?

Comment: `update control {
                Auth-Type := \`/etc/raddb/serp.sh '%{User-Name}' '%{User-Password}' '%{Client-IP-Address}'\`
        }`
this is part of my sites-enabled/default, in authorize section

Comment: I've changed brackets on user file to \` \` instead of  " " , and make script to return 0, and echo "Accept" - working great!

Comment: Yes because the backticks expand to the value the script writes to stdout.